# Arduino UNO: Autonomous Firetruck Coding (Fire Detection) and Connection (Water Pump) Problem

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently working on an autonomous firetruck project. Its already doing obstacle avoidance however, I still don't know the proper code for fire detection. It already detects fire but what I want to happen is the motor will stop for a second when it detects fire then it will go forward directly to the fire and put it off using a water pump. I already made a code but it is not working. Secondly, where I will insert the GND and VCC of the water pump? I don't know its connection.

Materials:
Arduino UNO
Ultrasonic Sensor
Flame Sensor
Servo Motor
Button
Mini Breadboard
L298n
2wd Robot Kit

Here is the code:

```
#include <Servo.h> 
#include "Ultrasonic.h"

const int button = 2;     
const int led    = 3;     
const int pump = 4;     
const int motorA1= 6;     
const int motorA2= 9;         
const int motorB1=10;     
const int motorB2=11;     
const int flame=12;
const int buzzer=13;

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(A4 ,A5); 
Servo myservo;         

int distance;         
int checkRight;
int checkLeft;
int function=0;         
int buttonState=0;            
int pos=90;            
int flag=0;           
int flame_detected=0;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 myservo.attach(5);      
 myservo.write(pos);        
 pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(led,  OUTPUT);
 pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motorA1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motorA2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motorB1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motorB2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(flame,INPUT);
 pinMode(pump,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
 flame_detected = digitalRead(flame);
  if (flame_detected == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("No flame detected. stay cool");

    //Check button state
    buttonState = digitalRead(button);
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); 

    if (buttonState == LOW) {
      delay(500);
      if ( flag == 0){
       function = 1;
       flag=1; 
      }
      else if ( flag == 1){ 
       function = 0;
       flag=0; 
     }    
   }

   if (function == 0){   
    myservo.write(90);    
    stop();          
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }
   else if (function == 1){
    //Read distance...
    distance = ultrasonic.Ranging(CM); 

   if (distance > 20){
    forward(); 

    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
   }
    else if (distance <=20){
    stop(); 

    digitalWrite(led,HIGH); 

    for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1){  
     myservo.write(pos);              
     delay(10);  
     //myservo.write(90);                     
    } 

    checkLeft = ultrasonic.Ranging(CM);   
    //myservo.write(90); 

    for(pos = 180; pos>=0; pos-=1){                               
    myservo.write(pos);              
    delay(10); 
    //myservo.write(90);                         
    }

    checkRight= ultrasonic.Ranging(CM);

          myservo.write(90); 

           if (checkLeft < checkRight){
             left();
             delay(400);          
             }
           else if (checkLeft > checkRight){
             right();
             delay(400);
           }
           else if (checkLeft <=10 && checkRight <=10){
             backward(); 
             left();
           }
   }   
 }

}

else if (flame_detected == 0) {
  Serial.println("Flame detected...! take action immediately.");
  buzzerwarning ();

  stop();


  if(distance > 25){
  forward();
  }
  else if (distance <= 25){
  stop();
  digitalWrite (pump, HIGH);
  }

  digitalWrite (pump,LOW);
  flame_detected == 1;
  }
}
void backward(){
 digitalWrite(motorA1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorA2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorB2, LOW); 
}

void forward(){
 digitalWrite(motorA1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorA2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorB1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB2, HIGH);
}

void left(){
 digitalWrite(motorA1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorA2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB2, HIGH);
}

void right(){
 digitalWrite(motorA1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorA2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorB1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(motorB2, LOW); 
}

void stop(){
 digitalWrite(motorA1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorA2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(motorB2, LOW);
}


void buzzerwarning () {
int i=0;

  do {
    i++;
    tone(buzzer, 7500); 
    delay (700);
    tone(buzzer, 5500); 
    delay (700);
    noTone (buzzer);
    delay (0);


  }
  while(i<2);


delay(0);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are 2 questions here.  It would be best to separate the two questions in two independent posts.  Also, simplify your program so it only contains the code which does not work as expected.  Some times there is a good reason to post all your code.  But in this case all you are asking about is moving toward a heat source.

Comment: `where I will insert the GND and VCC of the water pump?` .... the pump is just a motor ... you control it the same way as the motors for the wheels

Comment: How is your code not working? What doesn't behave as expected? You always have to provide a full problem description

Comment: What do you use the L298N for? If it's for the pump, a simple transistor would do the job as well

Comment: Usually, code using `delay()`s is poor. You should implement a (non-blocking) state machine. This will probably solve one of your problems

Comment: I use a relay for the pump and it is now working the only problem is the code

This is the part of the code that is not working:

  if(distance > 25){
  forward();
  }
  else if (distance <= 25){
  stop();
  digitalWrite (pump, HIGH);
  }
  
  digitalWrite (pump,LOW);
  flame_detected == 1;
  }